# Dereferencing operator -> not working

Tags: perl, reference

I'm learning references. In the book Intermediate Perl (2nd edition) : CHAPTER 5 (References and Scoping), Following code is given:

```
my $ref;
{
    my @skipper = qw(blue_shirt hat jacket preserver sunscreen); # ref count is 1
    $ref = \@skipper; # ref count is 2
    print "$ref−>[2]\n"; # prints jacket\n
}
print "$ref−>[2]\n"; # still prints jacket\n # ref count is 1
```

When I ran this code,  it gave the output:

`ARRAY(0x83fc890)−>[2]`

`ARRAY(0x83fc890)−>[2]`

Thought it was supposed to print jacket.

http://ideone.com/y8ZLsp

When I tried running it without the quotes, I got the output:

`Unrecognized character \xE2; marked by <-- HERE after print $ref<-- HERE near column 12 at prog.pl line 5.`

http://ideone.com/V9GbUe

I tried some more:

`$$ref[2]` #Worked

`${$ref}[2]` #Worked

So,

Is the code given in the book wrong? (I was told it's a good book - I'm reading it and I'm finding it great. Not sure it was a printing mistake or I'm doing something wrong)

Answer (score 7):

You are using the minus sign `"−"` (`U+2212`). This is not the same as ASCII hyphen-minus `"-"` (`U+002D`).

Let's see what your code actually contains:

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper <<'END';
my $ref;
{
    my @skipper = qw(blue_shirt hat jacket preserver sunscreen); # ref count is 1
    $ref = \@skipper; # ref count is 2
    print "$ref−>[2]\n"; # prints jacket\n
}
print "$ref−>[2]\n"; # still prints jacket\n # ref count is 1
END
```

Output (newlines changed to physical newlines):

```
my \$ref;
{
    my \@skipper = qw(blue_shirt hat jacket preserver sunscreen); # ref count is 1
    \$ref = \\\@skipper; # ref count is 2
    print \"\$ref\342\210\222>[2]\\n\"; # prints jacket\\n
}
print \"\$ref\342\210\222>[2]\\n\"; # still prints jacket\\n # ref count is 1
```

Comment: Oh. That was so stupid of me. :( How to avoid this. I use UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: What editor are you using? I simply type the normal hyphen-minus on my keyboard, and everything works fine.

Comment: Kate. Never had any issues.

Comment: Nice, me too! Are you using any freakish compose-sequences or unusual keybord settings? There is no reason for the minus key to not make the ASCII hyphen-minus.

Comment: Are you using an US keyboard? Keyboards for other countries may have different code points for their characters.

Comment: @amon Yes. :( It's so embarassing. Sorry for the trouble. Thank you for the explanation.